# AS3 - Interactive Bingo Grid

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm working on a Flash project that will be used to display numbers that are called for a game of Bingo.  A person will control the board being displayed to a live audience by clicking on one of 75 "covered" tiles.  Upon click of a tile (ex: button1), 3 things need to happen:

1) the click triggers a short MovieClip (ex: Number1) animation that takes up most of the screen showing "1"

2) the MovieClip (Number1) unloads itself and we see the grid again

3) The tile covering the "1" on the grid is removed so that we see which numbers have been called

I have the following code that is working correctly to remove the individual [!tiles upon click:

```
button1.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, Reveal1);
function Reveal1(event:MouseEvent) {

if (button1.alpha == 1){
  button1.alpha = 0;} else {button1.alpha = 1}
}
```

What is the simplest way for me to load/unload a MovieClip for each of the 75 numbers when their respective tiles are clicked?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Event.currentTarget is the reference to the button that is the event source.

```
button1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Reveal1);

function Reveal1(event:MouseEvent)
{
    var aButton:InteractiveObject = event.currentTarget as InteractiveObject;
    aButton.alpha == (aButton.alpha == 1)? 0: 1;

    // and/or
    aButton.parent.removeChild(aButton);
}
```

Comment: Is "aButton" a different button than "button1"?

Comment: aButton is a variable. You subscribe **ALL** the buttons to the Reveal1 methon and aButton accepts a reference to whichever button is clicked.

Comment: Got it, thank you. And in your code, which part do I substitute with with the name of my MovieClips in my library? (Ex: Movie1, Movie2, Movie75)

Comment: I don't understand the question. Add some code so I can see what you are willing to achieve.

Comment: @Chance the beauty of it is you don't need to use the individual button names. What if you had 200 buttons? What a nightmare! This code works on all the buttons regardless of their name.